# Why is the SQL query from Entity Framework not visible in the Sql Server Profiler when query contains declared variables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-profiler

Piece of code:

```
        using (var dc = new Database())
        {
            var results = from a in dc.Article
                          where a.IdNeswpaper == 12
                          select new
                          {
                              a.Id,                               
                          };
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = results;
        }
```

This query is visible in Sql Profiler, but this:

```
        int idNews = 12;
        using (var dc = new Database())
        {
            var results = from a in dc.Article
                          where a.IdNeswpaper == idNews
                          select new
                          {
                              a.Id,                               
                          };
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = results;
        }
```

isn't visible, both are done correctly and the data is displayed.
Why the second query isn't visible in Sql Profiler?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to tell you, but you must look better. The query IS there. Maybe you filter it out?

Point is - there is no way to pull data out of a database via a connection without submitting SQL text. None. So, to get the data the query has to be there.

Comment: I know, but query is not visible only in second example and it's weird